# Integrate AngularJS App with SoftwareAG webMethods Integration Server

Tags: rest, angularjs, designer, angularjs-resource, webmethods

I have been trying to set up a sample AngularJS app with webMethods Integration Server on the backend.  Using $resource, I can easily pull normal JSON files and manipulate the data within the file.  However, the goal is that I want to create services in webMethods Designer and call them from AngularJS using $resource to display the data in my app.  The problem is that from AngularJS I cannot extract the data I need from the service that I'm creating in Designer.  In Designer I can use (in WMPublic) documentToJSONString, and output something like:

```
jsonString  {"id":"1", "name":"Dan", "quantity":"3"}
```

But I cannot extract the data because this is not a pure JSON string.  Does anyone know how to (1) extract the JSON string output data using AnularJS or (2) output a JSON document from Designer?  I am calling a REST service; something to the effect of

```
http://localhost:2222/rest/Get/getOrderData
```

from my services.js file in AngularJS.

Here is my services.js file:

/* Services */

```
var orderServices = angular.module('orderServices', ['ngResource']);

orderServices.factory('Order', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:2222/rest/REST/getOrderData', {}, {
       query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}
  });

}]);
```

Then, in my app, I want to use an ng-repeat to call things like {{order.id}}, {{order.name}} etc.  Is anyone good with webMethods and Angular or done this before?

Comment: Can you hit that URL in your browser and paste what you get?

Answer (score 0):

To force the response that you want, I would have used the service 
**pub.flow:setResponse** mapping the jsonString to it's string parameter and probably hardcoded (eww!) the contentType parameter to 'application/json'

You may also need to use the service **pub.flow:setResponseCode** to set the response code.

They would be the last services in getOrderData

I would have invoked it using the below (where namespace is the folder structure in designer)

```
http://localhost:2222/invoke/namespace:getOrderData
```

The above applies to Integration Server V8 and it looks like you're using V9 since some of the services that you mention didn't exist in V8.  This would also apply to a normal flow service, not a specific REST one (assuming they exist in V9).